# How to connect two Linux computers with bluetooth?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, bluetooth

I have 2 computers, both have Ubuntu 10.10 desktop edition installed. Both have bluetooth dangle, but the manufacturers are different. I want to connect the two computers and share the Internet connection.

On computer A, I set the bluetooth to 'visible'; and on computer B, I started the 'setup new device' process. On computer B, it can find A, but when it pops up a dialog and ask me to enter the PIN code on A, I cannot see anywhere on A that I can enter the code. I also tried from the other direction, but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not tried it, but here's a link for [bluetooth networking with linux](http://triptico.com/docs/bluetooth.html), or [this tutorial](http://www.penguintutor.com/tutorials/viewdoc.php?doc=bluetooth-network-tutorial) (both found via a google search for `bluetooth networking linux`).